# Replace vector in matrix using malloc and pointer

Tags: c++

My task is to replace elements of vector and elements on diagonal matrix. Vector is entered by user and the matrix is random. For example, I write vector:

```
1 2 3
```

And the random matrix is

```
7 0 0
0 3 0
0 0 8
```

I must get this

```
1) 7 3 8



2) 

    1 0 0
    0 2 0
    0 0 3
```

The first part of it i got, but the second I'm stacked.  Here is entering vector:

```
int size;

  std::cout << ("Enter the dimentoinal of vector and matrix (enter one number): ");
  std::cin >> size;
  int * arrayPtr = (int*) calloc(size,sizeof(int)); 

  if (arrayPtr == NULL) exit (1);                   

  for (int ix = 0; ix < size; ix++)                 
  {
    std::cout << "Enter element #" << ix<< "   ";
    std::cin >> arrayPtr[ix];

  }
 system ("clear") ;
  std::cout << "\n\nResulting vector is:\n[ ";
  for (int ix = 0; ix < size; ix++)    
  {             
      std::cout << arrayPtr[ix] << " ";
  }
      cout << "]\n\n\n" ;
```

Here is code, that not working(on the screen is not correct result):

```
cout << "The new matrix is :\n" ;
int * matr_n = (int*) calloc(size,sizeof(int));

    cout << "\n" ;
   for (int ix = 0 ; ix<size; ix++)
   {
       matr_n = &arrayPtr[ix] ;
       cout << *matr_n << "  " ;

        for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
          cout << "\n" ;
          for (int j = 0; j<size; j++)
            {
               if (i==j)
                  {
                    cout << *matr_n << " " ;
                   }
               else 
                 cout << 0 << " " ;

            }
      }
}
```

I know that the problem is in using pointers or malloc/calloc function, but for beginner is hard to catch it fast.
Can you fix it, please?

Comment: **Indent** your code for Christ's sake.

Comment: *Why* do you want to use `malloc` in C++? That's pretty much always a bad idea

Comment: *"Can you fix it, please?"* - Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl                                                                                       
mat = diag(vec) ;
get an error: ‘diag’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @АдольфінаБучинська `int * matr_n = (int*) calloc(size,sizeof(int));... matr_n = &arrayPtr[ix] ;` -- Memory leak.  You allocate memory and then you replace the pointer returned to you from `calloc` with another pointer `&arrayPtr`.  Put all of this away and use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

The inner for-loop which prints the matrix should be separated from the loop which calculates its values.

In other words, you'll need to change the bottom part of the code as follows:

```
for (int ix = 0; ix < size; ix++)
{
    matr_n = &arrayPtr[ix];
    std::cout << *matr_n << "  ";
}
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int j = 0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if (i == j)
        {
            std::cout << *matr_n << " ";
        }
        else
            std::cout << 0 << " ";

    }
}
```

Comment: @lbezito if my vector is 1 2 3 i get this on the screen: diagonal matrix of 3